# Superellipse parametric equation

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves

$$\left|\frac{x}{a}\right|^n+\left|\frac{y}{b}\right|^n=1,\qquad\quad n\gt2$$
$$\text{can be rewritten as}$$
$$x(t)=a\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n}\quad\vee\quad x(t)=-a\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n}$$
$$y(t)=b\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}\quad\vee\quad y(t)=-b\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}$$

How is it that the equation of a superellipse can be rewritten as above. I do understand that they use $\cos^2 t+sin^2 t=1.$ However, I don't understand why $a$ and $b$ can be negative or positive?

Comment: $a\cdot |\cos t|^{2/n}$ is always positive. You need all four sign combinations to get all four quadrants.

Comment: Because the absolute values swallow the sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the parametic expressions satisfy the superellipse equation, the ones with the positive sign represent the superellipse in the first quadrant, the ones x-negative and -positive in the second, and so on.

Indeed:

$$\left|\frac{x}{a}\right|^n+\left|\frac{y}{b}\right|^n=\left|\frac{\pm a\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n}}{a}\right|^n+\left|\frac{\pm b\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}}{b}\right|^n=
\\=\left|\pm 1\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n}\right|^n+\left|\pm 1\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}\right|^n=|\pm 1|\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)^{2/n}\right|^n+|\pm 1|\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)^{2/n}\right|^n=\\=\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$$

Suppose wlog $a,b >0$ otherwise just switch the sign, thus we have

Firt quadrant $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$:
$$\begin{cases} 
x(t)=a\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n} \\
y(t)=b\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}
\end{cases}$$

Second quadrant $t\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$:
$$\begin{cases} 
x(t)=-a\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n} \\
y(t)=b\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}
\end{cases}$$

Third quadrant $t\in[\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2})$:

$$\begin{cases} 
x(t)=-a\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n} \\
y(t)=-b\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}
\end{cases}$$

Forth quadrant $t\in[\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi)$:
$$\begin{cases} 
x(t)=a\,\cdot\,\left|\cos(t)\right|^{2/n} \\
y(t)=-b\,\cdot\,\left|\sin(t)\right|^{2/n}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: But how can we than say (x/-a)^n=cos^2t and (x/-b)^n=sin^2t? If a or b is negative than cos/sin will also be negative. Should there not also be a negative sign in front of cos/sin in thay case?

Comment: Whatever is the sign of a and b the parametric equation s satisfy the superellipse equation. If a or b are negative nothing change. EG if a and b are both negative, the parametric equations with minus sign represent the equation in the first quadrant and so on.

Comment: I don't exactly get that compared to cos and sin. Maybe you could explain it in another way? That would be great.

Comment: @AGR I've update a full answer, I hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

It's required for the symmetry, so that the curve can exist in all four quadrants.Perhaps a better way to write this is

$$
x=a|\cos t|^{2/n}\text{sgn}(\cos t)\\
y=b|\sin t|^{2/n}\text{sgn}(\sin t)\\
t\in[0,2\pi]
$$

where $\text{sgn}$ is the sign function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use quadrants for the superellipse equation, it is also possible write it as one single equation:

The polar form of the superellipse is

$\left (\begin{array}{l}r=a\cdot b\cdot \dfrac{1}{\left (\left |a\cdot sin(t)\right |^{n}+\left |b\cdot cos(t)\right |^{n}\right )^{\dfrac{1}{n}}}\\\end{array}\right )$

and to convert the polar equation into a parametric equation:

$\left (\begin{array}{l}x=r\cdot cos(t)\\y=r\cdot sin(t)\end{array}\right )$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is still unclear about it, I just suggest using one formula instead of using formulas for each quadrant?

Comment: Answer itself is okay, but it's better to reuse symbols defined by asker.